# Feathers client doesn't receive websocket events from server

Tags: node.js, socket.io, feathersjs

I have a feathers application in both frontend and backend side, I want to listen to some events like `created` of some entities but the client doesnt recieve events, I followed this instruction

https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/client/socketio.html#socketio-socket

Comment: socket.io is not a websocket client

Answer (score 3):

You also need to configure [the channels](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/channels.html) that are used to determine which client should see those websocket events. By default all events are only sent to authenticated users. And example how to set up authentication is part of [the guide](https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/basics/frontend.html).

Comment: Hi is it possible to disable this requirement, of authentication? and how do we do it?